# Excluding specific mimeType from Google Drive API results

Tags: javascript, api, google-drive-api, hello.js

I'm using hello.js and retrieving a list of the users files via javascript, but I want to be able to exclude specific mimetypes from the results that are sent back.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=%22root%22+in+parents+and+trashed=false&maxResults=100&access_token=<access_token>
```

Is there a query param that can be added to exclude results like Maps?

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters, "mimeType != MIME type of the file" is supported. Are you saying this doesn't work?

Comment: @pinoyyid No I'm not able necessarily to try that, I'm using hellojs to manage the auth and api calls and I am unsure of how to make that request happen with hellojs. I should've asked how to configure that in Hellojs

Comment: I'm not sure that hello.js would be expected to handle that level of detail of the Drive API. afaik it's focus is more on the generic OAuth and identity related aspects of Cloud APIs, rather than on the nitty gritty of (say) the Drive API. You're probably better using the Google gapi library, or coding your own REST calls, or using ngGAPI (for AngularJS only) .

Comment: @pinoyyid I see, I agree I've been slowly coming to that conclusion but since Hellojs already had api calls built I was hoping to get away with just using or finding a solution via hellojs that would meet my needs. Thanks

Comment: HelloJS will give you all the flexibility you need when it comes to using individual webservices APIs (see my answer below). Albeit the documentation probably doesn't explain that very well, and focuses on its own mapping and standardization of endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example the mimeType "image/png" is excluded.

```
function getImages() {
   var gl = hello('google');
   gl.login({scope:'files'}).then(function(){

       // Make request for files add the proprietary parameter 'q'
       // See https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters for more.
       return gl.api("me/files", {q:"mimeType != 'image/'"});
   }).then(log.bind(null,'.demo2'),log.bind(null,'.demo2'));
}
```

Comment: Nice thanks, yea I ended up finding something similar to this and used this method!